# VSCode Jupyter hangs-up when using Sympy + IPython.display

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, python-3.9

I'm trying to display interim results in my Jupyter notebook in VS Code.

I'm executing the code, written in a .py-file in the python interactive window.

Everything works fine until the program comes to a `display(expr)` call: The call is not executed, because the jupyter kernel stops responding now.

Comment: try using `sympy.init_printing(use_latex="mathjax", latex_mode="equation")`

Comment: Yes, that works, thanks! Please explain those arguments, as it is not really clear for me why is work now and post it as an answer!